# How to organize rails class naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to organize my active jobs classes in rails, for that reason I want to have parent classes that define a category, so I am writing

```
class EmailJobs::MyEmailJob < ApplicationJob
```

but this gives me an error

```
uninitialized constant EmailJobs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put this class in  `jobs/email_jobs/my_email_job.rb`

See:

- https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#file-structure
- (old) https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#project-structure